# Trace x,y of movieclip that is animated through timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, position, movieclip

I am trying to trace the position of a movieclip(that contains a simple timeline animation inside) so that I can attach another movieclip to be able to follow it.

How can I do that?

empty = the movieclip that contains timeline animation

mc = the movieclip I want to follow the "empty" movieclip

```
empty.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onMove);

function onMove(event:Event):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = new SmokeTween();
    mc.x = empty.x;
    mc.y = empty.y;
    mc.rotation = Math.round(Math.random() * 70);
    this.addChild(mc);
}
```

Actually I went  into "empty" mc and and used this code and seems to work fine:

```
this.addEventListener ( Event.ENTER_FRAME, traceFrame );

function traceFrame ( e : Event ) : void
{
    if (e.target.currentFrame > 0){
        MovieClip(parent.parent).mc.x = e.target.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? `trace(MovieClip.x, MovieClip.y)` would do the trick.

Comment: Yes but it only traces the starting position. I suppose I need to trace the position of the current frame of the movieclip(since it's timeline animation) to achieve that but not sure how. Updated first post with code.

Comment: You can just add it in your `onMove` function.

Comment: Yes but as I said it traces the first position(x,y) only so the position number is always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I went into "empty" mc and and used this code and seems to work fine:

```
this.addEventListener ( Event.ENTER_FRAME, traceFrame );

function traceFrame ( e : Event ) : void
{
    if (e.target.currentFrame > 0){
        mc.x = e.target.x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that `empty` doesn't animate, so you need to use the root's `ENTER_FRAME` event instead of `empty`'s:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onMove); // no "empty."
function onMove(event:Event):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = new SmokeTween();
    mc.x = empty.x;
    mc.y = empty.y;
    mc.rotation = Math.round(Math.random() * 70);
    this.addChild(mc);
}
```

As your project gets bigger, you'll also find that recycling objects becomes important (especially in Flash). Keep an array of SmokeTweens and keep recycling them, instead of creating new ones and letting them delete themselves.